# Laravel 5.2 .htaccess and 500 internal error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, centos

I have deployed my Laravel 5.2 project on Host.

The project works fine on local but gets me `500 Internal Server Error` error when I deployed it on Host because of `.htaccess` file!

Here my `.htaccess` file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

P.S:

Required PHP extensions for Laravel is installed and enabled.
I also granted `775` permission to `storage` but nothing changed!

Any helps would be great appreciated.

Comment: Did you look into error log?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have permission to use *.htaccess* file in that folder by checking `AllowOverride` directive in you server config file. (usually **httpd.ini**).

Full guide: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Check if mod_rewrite is installed and enabled in your php.ini file.
Here is a basic explanation on how to install/enable mod_rewrite in apache: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5758551/3435728

Edit:

Make sure you have read permision on your *.htaccess* file

Answer (score 0):

maybe not supported MultiViews options

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Comment: That should'nt be the problem as long as the extension is being checked at `<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>`

Comment: have you used public folder in local server like localhos/abc/public/

Answer (score 0):

Try to follows below step as much you can do.

```
1. connect to hosting via SSH

2. install composer

3. in cpanel open Select PHP version and choose 5.4. (I also set phar extension)

4. install laravel: php composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel myproject --prefer-dist

5. copy everything from myproject/public to public_html

6. open public_html/index.php and set:

7. require __DIR__.'/../myproject/bootstrap/autoload.php';

8. $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../myproject/bootstrap/start.php';
```

for the 7 and 8 steps give the path where you source has so that file find that files

Hope this is works.